# Celery worker is out of sync when doing local development

Tags: python, heroku, celery

Currently I have a chatbot that is hosted on heroku that uses Redis+Celery+RabbitMQ. I noticed an issue these past days when I decided to develop locally the celery terminal would show:

```
[2023-04-13 17:59:28,740: WARNING/MainProcess] Substantial drift from celery@1d4a4d36-16ad-45bf-afde-7da48e1ad95a may mean clocks are out of sync.  Current drift is 18000 seconds.  [orig: 2023-04-13 17:59:28.740113 recv: 2023-04-13 22:59:28.402314]
```

I went into the Heroku CLI and noticed that when starting my local app it would show sync with @pcname. So it seems this bug happens only when my app is running on Heroku and not offline. When the app is offline in heroku everything works great.

I double checked the .env file and it has the local rabbitmq url.

How can I fix that?

I tried everything but nothing works. I am not sure why this is not working.

Comment: Hello "I tried everything but nothing works" is absolutely not a way to describe what you tried and what failed on this website. That would actually indicate that there's no solution if you tried "everything". Please be **as precise as possible** with your questions.